# Mostrar valor de propriedades ao invés do nome da classe no DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho uma DataGridView que deverá mostrar dados entre tabelas relacionadas e não consigo que mostre os dados correctamente, mostra o nome do nameSpace seguido do nome da classe. Vi algumas coisas e mostravam um override, mas também li que não é boa prática e sugeriam que fizesse através do evento cellFormating.

O que me acontece é isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta classe esta no namespace DTO

```
 public class Despesa
{
    public int id_despesa { get; set; }
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
    public Mes mes { get; set; }
    public string previsao { get; set; }
    public Forma_Pagamento forma_Pagamento { get; set; }
    public Periodo periodo { get; set; }
}
```

Depois a minha colecção de despesas vai herdar uma lista de despesas

```
public class DespesaCollection : List<Despesa>
{
}
```

Na camada de negócio coloco todas as despesas dentro da coleção

```
foreach (DataRow linha in DataTableDespesas.Rows)
            {
                Despesa despesa = new Despesa();
                despesa.id_despesa = Convert.ToInt32(linha["id_despesa"]);
                despesa.categoria = new Categoria();
                despesa.categoria.id_categoria = Convert.ToInt32(linha["id_categoria"]);
                despesa.descricao = linha["descricao"].ToString();
                despesa.valor = Convert.ToDecimal(linha["valor"]);
                despesa.mes = new Mes();
                despesa.mes.id_mes = Convert.ToInt32(linha["id_mes"]);
                despesa.previsao = linha["previsao"].ToString();
                despesa.forma_Pagamento = new Forma_Pagamento();
                despesa.forma_Pagamento.id_forma_pagamento = Convert.ToInt32(linha["id_formaPagamento"]);
                despesa.periodo = new Periodo();
                despesa.periodo.id_periodo = Convert.ToInt32(linha["id_periodo"]);

                despesaCollection.Add(despesa);
            }
```

E aqui é como carrego a colecção para exibir no dataGridView.

```
 private void carregarDataGridView()
    {
        DespesaCollection despesaCollection = new DespesaCollection();
        DespesaNegocio despesaNegocio = new DespesaNegocio();

        despesaCollection = despesaNegocio.ConsultarTudo();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = despesaCollection;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Mostre como você está dando bind no grid. A solução eu tenho, várias inclusive.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta e deixei tudo de necessário para que me possa mostrar como se faz, obrigado!!! @jbueno

Comment: @jbueno fiquei muito curioso para saber quais as soluções que tinha para o meu caso!

Comment: Postei uma resposta, Diogo. Espero que seja útil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada: **esqueça a história de usar o `CellFormatting`** pra este tipo de coisa. Com um volume considerável de dados, você já começará a ter problemas de performance, isso sem contar que existem formas bem mais simples de fazer isso.

Pelo que você postou, não vejo necessidade nenhuma de criar uma `Collection` para jogar os dados no grid. Como você já está seguindo este padrão, talvez a melhor solução seja realmente sobrescrever o método `ToString()` de todos os seus *models*, desde que isso não te atrapalhe em nada.

Pelo que entendi, você faz a consulta no banco de dados, essa consulta te devolve um `DataTable` e dele você criar uma coleção de `Despesas` para jogar no grid. Tendo um `DataTable`, você já consegue fazer o *bind* num `DataGridView`. Então, se todos os necessários que você precisa mostrar no *grid* estão no `DataTable`, você pode fazer assim

```
private void carregarDataGridView()
{
    var dataTable = RetonarDataTable(); // Vamos supor que este método devolva o datatable

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Uma outra forma, também interessante, de resolver isso é criar uma "classe intermediária" que conterá apenas as informações necessárias no *grid*. Aí, ao invés de instanciar uma `DespesaCollection`, você pode criar uma lista desta classe e fazer o *bind*. Veja o exemplo abaixo

```
// essa é a classe "intermediária"
public class DespesaViewModel
{
    public int id_despesa { get; set; }
    public string nome_categoria { get; set; } // Apenas supus que deveria ser assim
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
    public string descr_mes { get; set; } // Apenas supus que deveria ser assim
    public string previsao { get; set; }
    public string forma_pagamento_descr { get; set; } // Apenas supus que deveria ser assim
    public Periodo periodo { get; set; }
}


var listaDespesas = new List<DespesaViewModel>();
foreach (DataRow linha in DataTableDespesas.Rows)
{
    var despesaVm = new DespesaViewModel
    {
        id_despesa = Convert.ToInt32(linha["id_despesa"]);      
        nome_categoria = Convert.ToInt32(linha["nome_categoria"]);
        ///... assim por diante
    }

    listaDespesas.Add(despesaVm);
}

private void carregarDataGridView()
{
    var lista = CarregarLista();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Estava a seguir um tutorial por isso estava a fazer dessa forma mas realmente fica muito mais simples se o meu DataGridView receber como dataSource o datatable. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Tutoriais geralmente são problemas, principalmente se for material em português. Você tem que pegar a essência e não tentar seguir receita de bolo, senão vai acabar sempre se deparando em problemas como este.

Answer (score 5):

Inicialmente eu vejo 2 opções:

Incluir uma nova propriedade `IdCategoria` no seu DTO:

```
public class Despesa
{
    public int id_despesa { get; set; }
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }
    public Mes mes { get; set; }
    public string previsao { get; set; }
    public Forma_Pagamento forma_Pagamento { get; set; }
    public Periodo periodo { get; set; }

    public string IdCategoria 
    {
       get { return categoria.id_categoria; }
    }
}
```

Ou fazer `override` do método `ToString` no objeto categoria:

```
public class Categoria
{
  .
  .
  .

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return id_categoria;
  }
}
```

(não tenho certeza que a segunda opção funciona corretamente no seu caso)

(Se o @jbueno responder, pode marcar a resposta dele. Ele veio te auxiliar primeiro. :) )

Comment: A primeira opção funcionou, mas depois fico com alguma dificuldade em editar as colunas do dataGridView porque coloquei dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Answer (score 2):

Quando voce vai bindar um objeto de um tipo não-primário, o winform chama o método ToString desse objeto. Então, se você fizer um override do método ToString de cada uma das classes que você tá mostrando (Categoria, Mes, Forma_Pagamento e Periodo) você consegue configurar o que aparece no grid.

Por exemplo, se eu quiser que aparece id_categoria

```
public class Categoria
{
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return id_categoria.ToString();
  }
}
```